# I have executed the topic model code successfully but I want unique wordclouds for each topic which I am currently struggling with

Tags: python, topic-modeling, word-cloud

```
# I am importing all the packages necessary for topic modelling in this step
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models
import os
from os import path
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import wordcloud
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
en_stop = set(get_stop_words('en'))
with open(os.path.join('D:\Users\kaila\jobdescription.txt')) as f:
    Reader = f.read()
# I am replacing all the unnecessary words for wordcloud analysis
Reader = Reader.replace("will", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("experience", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("work", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("years", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("please", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("apply", " ")


texts = unicode(Reader, errors='replace')
tdm = []

raw = texts.lower()
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in en_stop]
tdm.append(stopped_tokens)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tdm)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(i) for i in tdm]
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=5, id2word =   dictionary)
for t in range(ldamodel.num_topics):
    print(ldamodel)
    print(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=5, num_words=8))
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(ldamodel.show_topic(t, 200)))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("Topic #" + str(t))
    plt.show()
```

By doing this I am getting the topic models and wordclouds but the results are very similar to each other. Is there anything I can do to get unique topic model and word cloud results ?